# JPA calculated field from other fields

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I am working on a system where I need to calculate points based on other properties in the same entity, i.e:

```
@Column(name = "distance")
private Integer distance;
@Column(name = "speed")
private Integer speed;
@Column(name = "calories")
private Integer calories ??
```

I need to calculate the calories based on speed and distance and persist this value ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new method, e.g `updateCalories()` that calculates current *calories* from *distance* and *speed*. Call this method everytime when *distance*, *speed* or other relevant fields change (setters, constructor) or use entity listeners to automatically invoke the method when entity is created/updated (@PreUpdate, @PrePersist...)

Answer (score 11):

There are two Options i would do this

**Option 1: @Formular**

```
@Formula("speed * distance")
private int calories;
```

Calories does not have its own column in the database, but you can access them via getter.. Calories will be calculated everytime you get the Entity from Database (Value is in Memory). An Advantage of @Formula is that you can write there a full Named Query  which may refer to a different table value

**Option 2: @PreUpdate and/or @PrePersist**

```
private int calories;

@PreUpdate
@PrePersist
public void calc() {
    calories = speed * distance;
}
```

In this Option, calories does have its own column in the database! 
Its already calculated and Persist, if you persist an Entity with EntityManager

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to persist them - because you can get the value of sum anyway any time. Why are you trying to save it?
    @Transient

```
public Integer getSum(){
return (distance + speed) * calories 
}
```

Use @Transient to be able not to save this value in DB.